# R optim() constraint optimization does not find the first best

Tags: r, matrix, optimization

my problem is summarized in finding a vector X with the best solution to the problem:
L is the profits,
R is the restrictions,
P is a constraint parameters matrix,

- max SUM_i (x_i * l_i)

or  max(t(L)%*%X)

- restriction

  - SUM_i(x_i*p_ij)<=r_j

or P%*%X <= R.

I find a solution for X, but not the best, which would be
fb = c(.217,0,0,23,2865,0,13,427).
How do I find the best solution?

code:

---

```
X<-matrix(rep(1,6),6,1)
P<-matrix(c(
    1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1,
    99.4, 37.75, 19.75, 54.40, 74.75, 53,
    2.400, 1.540, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    2.400, 1.960, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1.800, 3.300, 5.330, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 2.070, 0, 8.700, 0,
    0, 0, .436, 0, 19.100, 12.363,
    0, 3.000, .364, 0, 9.100, 26.737  ), 
9,6,1)

L <- matrix(c(83.4, 72.35, 27.3, 72.05, 217.25, 455), 6,1)
R <- matrix(c(60,60,2000,351,448,479,338,424,359),9,1)

farm<- function(par, P,R,  L){
   trues<- P%*%par<=R
 if (min(trues)==1 && min(par)>=0) {
    return(-t(L)%*%par)
     }
 else{
     return(0)
 }
}

mtds = c("Nelder-Mead", "BFGS", "CG", "L-BFGS-B", "SANN","Brent")
out <- optim(par = X,  # initial guess
             fn  = farm,
             P   = P,
             R   = R ,
             L   = L,
             method  = mtds[5]) 


# my result
t(L)%*%out$par
#A matrix: 1 × 1 of type dbl
#7419.596

# the first best
fb<- matrix(c(.217,0,0,23.2865,0,13.427),6,1)
t(L)%*%fb
#A matrix: 1 × 1 of type dbl
#7805.175
```

Comment: Is it the same result for all the `methods`? It could be that the solver gets stuck at a 'local' minimum rather than a 'global' minimum - this is fairly common. You can try a few different initial guesses to get the global min. Alternatively, you can also look at implementing a simple Newton-Raphson method here instead of using a library.

Comment: No, it is the best solution between the methods. I tested them all from "Nelder-Mead" to "SANN"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try `fmincon` from package `pracma`

```
library(pracma)
objfun <- function(x) -t(L)%*%x
res <- fmincon(x0 = X,fn = objfun,A = P,b = R,lb = rep(0,length(X)))
```

and you will see that

```
> res$par
[1]  4.201711e-16 -1.239088e-15  1.863081e-17  2.310286e+01
[5]  5.566620e-01  1.323762e+01

> -res$value
         [,1]
[1,] 7808.615
```

Comment: Don't use `fmincon()`, this is just a wrapper for `solnl` in package NlcOptim. Use the original, not a wrapped ghost. I know that Thomas is advocating `fmincon` for nonlinear optimization problems, but this is simply 'no good'.  
By the way, the best way to handle this kind of problems is -- as Enrico has rightly stated below -- to look at it as a linear programming problem. His answer should have been starred.

Answer (score 1):

That looks very much like a model that could be solved by a linear programme.

```
library("Rglpk")
Rglpk_solve_LP(obj = L,
               mat = P,
               dir = rep("<=", 9),
               rhs = R,
               max = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, the linear programme solution works perfectly.